# Sort array of objects based on order of another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of objects and I need to match the order of one of the arrays with the other. Here's an example:

```
const outOfOrderArray = [{field: 'foo'}, {field: 'bar'}, {field: 'bazz'}, {field: 'bizz'}];

const arrayInProperOrder = [{field: 'bizz'}, {field: 'bazz'}, {field: 'foo'}, {field: 'bar'}];
```

What can I do to make the `outOfOrderArray` match the order of objects in `arrayInProperOrder`?

Comment: Why don't you just copy the arrayInProperOrder?

Comment: Simply compare the two and return the in order one

Comment: Will these arrays have objects with unique values (bazz, bar, foo etc.) or these arrays can contain the duplicates too e.g. `const outOfOrderArray = [{field: 'foo'}, {field: 'foo'}, {field: 'bar'}, {field: 'bazz'}, {field: 'bizz'}]` where `{field: 'foo'}` is appearing 2 times,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do it in one less loop than the solution of @Faly. There is no need to sort the array. You may just loop over `arrayInProperOrder` and find matching element from `outOfOrderArray` so that the latter becomes in order.

```js
const outOfOrderArray = [{field: 'foo'}, {field: 'bar'}, {field: 'bazz'}, {field: 'bizz'}];
const arrayInProperOrder = [{field: 'bizz'}, {field: 'bazz'}, {field: 'foo'}, {field: 'bar'}];

const newArray = [];

arrayInProperOrder.forEach(item => {
  const original = outOfOrderArray.find(i => i.field === item.field);

  if (original) {
    newArray.push(original);
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

If you need it in place, just assign `newArray` to `outOfOrderArray`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temp object to store the order and use it as a basis on `sort()`

Use `Infinity` as the default value if some field is not found on temp object.

```js
const outOfOrderArray = [{field: 'foo'}, {field: 'bar'}, {field: 'bazz'}, {field: 'bizz'}];

const arrayInProperOrder = [{field: 'bizz'}, {field: 'bazz'}, {field: 'foo'}, {field: 'bar'}];

//Make a temp object - This will store the order of the field. This nessasary so that no need to search every reiteration on sort()
const tempObj = arrayInProperOrder.reduce((c, v, i) => Object.assign(c, {[v.field]: i + 1}), {});

//Sort the array.
outOfOrderArray.sort((a, b) => (tempObj[a.field] || Infinity) - (tempObj[b.field] || Infinity));

console.log(outOfOrderArray);
```

Doc: [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.sort` and `array.prototype.findIndex`:

```js
const outOfOrderArray = [{field: 'foo'}, {field: 'bar'}, {field: 'bazz'}, {field: 'bizz'}];
const arrayInProperOrder = [{field: 'bizz'}, {field: 'bazz'}, {field: 'foo'}, {field: 'bar'}];

outOfOrderArray.sort(
    (a, b) => arrayInProperOrder.findIndex(e => e.field === a.field) -  arrayInProperOrder.findIndex(e => e.field === b.field)
);

console.log(outOfOrderArray);
```

If you care about performance, you can build an object allowing you to get the index by the field value, from arrayInProperOrder array:

```js
const outOfOrderArray = [{field: 'foo'}, {field: 'bar'}, {field: 'bazz'}, {field: 'bizz'}];
const arrayInProperOrder = [{field: 'bizz'}, {field: 'bazz'}, {field: 'foo'}, {field: 'bar'}];
const indexes = arrayInProperOrder.reduce((m, o, i) => (m[o.field] = i, m), {});

outOfOrderArray.sort(
    (a, b) => indexes[a.field] -  indexes[b.field]
);

console.log(outOfOrderArray);
```

Comment: Performing a two linear searches at every step of a sort operation doesn't seem like a great idea. The `.sort()` method really isn't needed in the first place.

Comment: Performance does not always pose problem, depending on the quantity of data to be processed